# Problems on having a field that will be null very often on a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, null, foreign-keys

I have a column that sometimes will be null. This column is also a foreign key, so I want to know if I'll have problems with performance or with data consistency if this column will have weight

I know its a foolish question but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem necessarily with this, other than it is likely indication that you *might* have poorly normalized design.  There might be performance implications due to the way indexes are structured and the sparseness of the column with nulls, but without knowing your structure or intended querying scenarios any conclusions one might draw would be pure speculation.

A better solution might be a **shared primary key** where table A has a primary key, and there is zero or one records in B with the same primary key.

If table A can have one or zero B, but more than one A can refer to B, then what you have is a one to many relationship.  This can be represented as Pieter laid out in his answer.  This allows multiple A records to refer to the same B, and in turn each B may optionally refer to an A.

So you see there are two optional structures to address this problem, and choosing each is not guesswork. There is a distinct rational between why you would choose one or the other, but it depends on the nature of your relationships you are modelling.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this design:

```
create table Master (
    ID       int identity not null primary key,
    DetailID int null references Detail(ID)
)
go
create table Detail (
    ID      int identity not null primary key
)
go
```

consider this instead

```
create table Master (
    ID      int identity not null primary key
)
go
create table Detail (
    ID       int identity not null primary key,
    MasterID int not null references Master(ID)
)
go
```

Now the Foreign Key is never null, rather the existence (or not) of the Detail record indicates whether it exists.

If a Detail can exist for multiple records, create a mapping table to manage the relationship.